# MATLAB-Undefined function or method 'mtimes' for input arguments of type 'cell'

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I'm trying to make a table in GUI. This table must be filled in by the user. When I want to edit the inserted data in an M-file, this error appeared.

```
??? Undefined function or method 'mtimes' for input arguments of type 'cell'.
```

I want to cross four columns and write the answer in the fifth column,
Please help me to correct this problem.

Comment: "Do it right." - Sorry, but that is the only way to help you with that sparse infrmation you give us. At least, a little bit of code would be helpful. Probably you do a `*` operation on a cell array instead of a numerical one...

Comment: What do you mean by "cross four columns"? The cross-product? traverse four columns and do an operation on each?

Answer (score 0):

You get the error if you have a situation similar to this:

```
a = {rand(4) 'A' 2i};
b = {rand(4) 'B' 6i};

a*b
```

e.g., you have two [cell-arrays](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2006/06/21/cell-arrays-and-their-contents/)(containers for generic type data), to which you apply an operation that is only defined for matrices (in this case, multiplication).

If you want to multiply each "thing" in `a` with each "thing" in `b`, you have to use `cellfun`:

```
>> cellfun(@mtimes, a, b, 'UniformOutput', false)
ans = 
    [4x4 double]    [4290]    [-12]
```

Note that the function `@mtimes` is an alias for the built-in `*`-operator. When used like this, it has to make sense for every element in the cell arrays.

Comment: Thank you Rody for you answer.
If i want to cross four number with cell type,is anyway to cross them only with one command such you said?

Comment: @AmirMohammadi: I'm not sure what you mean with "cross". Can you explain a bit more what you want exactly?

Comment: @AmirMohammadi: Well, you could do `a{5} = a{1}*a{2}*a{3}*a{4}`. Not very general, but it works. A more general approach: `b=a{1}; for ii=2:size(a,2), b=b*a{ii}; end, a{end+1}=b;`